# How work with Javascript Date timezone showing less a day

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset, date-conversion

The application is based in Portugal whose timezone is UTC+00:00 but now is daylight saving.

Here I received a range of date values from the Datepicker component, which was '01/04/2022 - 01/05/2022' and saved it in a state

```
 const handleCreationDateChange = (dateRange: {
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
  }) => {
    if (dateRange) {
      setCreationDate(dateRange);
    } else {
      setCreationDate(null);
    }
  };
```

at this point, the date range object is correct, like the image below

```
const payload = {
    creationDateFrom: dateRange.creationDateFrom,
    creationDateTo: dateRange.creationDateTo
}
```

[image: date range object]

but the payload object which was sent to the server shows less a day
[image: date range object]

for a user in Brasil, it shows the correct date but takes a different timezone
[image]

I've tried converting to `.toIsoString()` then converting back to Date but it didn't work

this needs to work for users from different timezones

Comment: Fri Apr 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT +0100 and 2022-03-31T23:00:00Z represent exactly the same instant in time, just with different offsets. Converting to string and back to Date does nothing except waste some CPU cycles.

Comment: @mplungjan—with that method, users with offset +9 or greater will still see a different local date. Where date only is required, a better solution might be to not to convert to Date objects, just keep the date as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format. Only convert to Date for calculations where necessary. Dates in that format can be compared with comparison operators (`<`, `>`, etc.) and sorted correctly as strings.

Comment: @RobG Actually I was a bit naive there. I was counting 14:00 as being within the highest offset, but I see I am wrong - it is an OFFSET of 14:00 hour that is the highest and not 2pm that is the latest...